# Max-width not working on table or tr?

Tags: html, css

I have a php which returns a row that can be very long, which results in horizontal scrollbars which are just plain annoying.

I tried using the css-property of max-width but it isn't making any difference. I want the row to basically break, when it reaches max screen-size to a new row.

Comment: Any code? Is it a long string w/o spaces? Why don't you use `width` instead of `max-width`?

Comment: What do you  mean by break? Do you want it to stop along with contents, or for it to grow in height and contents wrap?

Comment: Please provide a [JSFiddle](jsfiddle.net) if you want a better help from us

Comment: Will provide JS in a few minutes if the solutions below don't work. Should have uploaded it with the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, try changing the table styling to include:

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

If that doesn't work change the td styling to include:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Comment: This worked td
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
table
{
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word;` like this : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B93XB/11/)